# carport to garage conversion

Tags: stucco

I have a garage that used to be a carport. Therefore the ceiling, clad with stucco, is not insulated. Do I need to pull down the stucco to properly have a vapour barrier when I insulate? or is the stucco enough of a vapour barrier?

Comment: Are you planning on heating/cooling the garage?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a second floor?  You don't really want an extra "vapor barrier" on anything that is (now) an interior surface.

And in general you want one and only one vapor barrier: all building spaces need to exchange humidity in at least one direction.  Put up two vapor barriers and the space in the middle will have the wrong humidity.